# Make it right and you'll be fine

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

`We are just some of many`
`One or more on every line`
`Don't jump to conclusions`
`Or there'll be confusion`
`Make it right and you'll be fine`

Can you determine what we are?

Comment: This isn't a limerick.

Comment: This is true; I thought I knew what a limerick is I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The **wrong** answer is

> the letter u

explanation:

We are just some of many

> 'u' is one of the 26 alphabets

One of us on every line

> 'u' happens to occur exactly once in each line, except line 3, (thanks @JonMark Perry, **this is why this is wrong**)

Don't jump to conclusions
Or there'll be confusion
Make it right and you'll be fine

> the answer 'u'(you) will be fine!

Comment: except for line 3 :)

Comment: concl**u**sions @JonMarkPerry

Comment: and also 'j**u**mp'

Comment: Line 3 has jump and conclusion so two instances of letter u for starters, but regardless this isn't the answer. In fact the correct answer does occur more than once on multiple lines.

Comment: @rtk wait... multiple lines? but "one of us on every line"...

Comment: I didn't think about it being interpreted as 'exactly one' rather 'at least one'. I suppose I could change the line to be 'One or more on every line' and still preserve the puzzle

Comment: Only other letters present in every line are N and O, it appears. (Along with Space and Line Break). Not sure if either of them work though.

Comment: that may be useful, thanks! @MichaelMoschella